# newQuote not defined unsure why

Tags: javascript

Another code to debug for me have to keep it the same as can't rewrite. But Im wondering why newQuote is spitting the error undefined. I also believe that I need to fix the timer setting to get it display as the var tick isn't being called but not 100% sure there any advice is appreciated as I can't find any error beyond the newQuote undefined

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Random Proverbs</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
function changeQuote() {
    quotes = new Array;
    quotes[0] = "Laughter is the best medicine.";
    quotes[1] = "Never look a gift horse in the mouth.";
    quotes[2] = "One good turn deserves another.";
    quotes[3] = "The early bird catches the worm.";
    quotes[4] = "Two is company, three is a crowd.";
    var newQuote = quotes[Math.round(Math.random()+quotes.length)];
    document.quoteform.quote.value = newQuote;
}
var tick = setInterval(changeQuote(), 1000); //missing time in milliseconds and double quotes not needed
// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="quoteform" action=""> <!--Was -->
<input type="text" size="50" id="quote" name="quote" /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(changeQuote, 1000)`

Comment: check your random number generator, you are going to be getting numbers out of range for your array

Comment: it should be Math.random() * quotes.length

Comment: Note `document.quoteform.quote` will not work in all browsers, I don't recommend getting DOM information that way. Rather use `document.getElementById("quote")`.

Comment: I'm not to rewrite the code just find and fix the bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change document.quoteform.quote to document.forms.quoteform.quote
then name the form quoteform
so the new javascript would look like

```
function changeQuote() {
    var quotes = new Array; //was var defintion
    quotes[0] = "Laughter is the best medicine.";
    quotes[1] = "Never look a gift horse in the mouth.";
    quotes[2] = "One good turn deserves another.";
    quotes[3] = "The early bird catches the worm.";
    quotes[4] = "Two is company, three is a crowd.";
    var newQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
    document.forms.quoteform.quote.value = newQuote; 
}
setInterval(changeQuote, 1000);
```

then all you need is change the id to name in the opening form tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Math.floor to avoid going outside the bounds of the array, and change the **+** to ***** to multiply the random number by the length of the array.

```
var newQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
```